# How to parser soap response in python?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, request, response, transport

I found some similar solution but it's not working for me. I would like to know the best practice of parser the soap response.

My source code is :

```
from zeep.transports import Transport

response = transport.post_xml(address, payload, headers)
print(type(response))
print(response.content)
```

Output:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>


How can I get the **a key** value form the response? which simple and best library I should use. 
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

It easily parse content and attribute.

Demo Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

content = b'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>UNKNOW_LOCALID</faultstring><detail><ns2:SoapServiceFaultUtilisation xmlns:ns2="http://nps.ideosante.com/"><codeStatus>70</codeStatus><message>Unknown local ID: 1990967085562</message></ns2:SoapServiceFaultUtilisation></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
print(content)

root = ET.fromstring(content)
print(root.find(".//codeStatus").text)
```

Result

```
b'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>UNKNOW_LOCALID</faultstring><detail><ns2:SoapServiceFaultUtilisation xmlns:ns2="http://nps.ideosante.com/"><codeStatus>70</codeStatus><message>Unknown local ID: 1990967085562</message></ns2:SoapServiceFaultUtilisation></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>' 
70
```

Comment: thanks for your soln.. Yes, Its work for me. But when I have something different response like : in a response sometime its coming without codeStatus key.

that time am getting error.

Comment: Can you update what is `response.content` into you question when you getting error?